# Using Android Voice Access to interact with Xamarin elements which don't show text

Tags: xamarin, accessibility

I have Xamarin buttons and CollectionView items which don't show text strings, and I'm working to support Android Voice Access being able to interact with those elements. Voice Access works fine with controls that do show text strings, but I've not found a way to interact with the controls that don't show text. I've set appropriate AutomationProperties.Name properties on the controls, but Voice Access doesn't interact with the controls when I speak those AutomationProperties.Name properties.

What can I set on the controls to have Voice Access work with controls, when the controls don't show text?

Comment: The offical document doesn't refer to the blank button. Android Voice Access  
get the control by what way is set. So you can post a issue to the developers.

Answer (score 0):

A snippet of code might help generate more answers but without seeing the code, you might need `android:importantForAccessibility="yes"` or `android:focusable="true"` and possibly `android:clickable="true"`

See also [What is the difference between Android focusable and importantForAccessibility when using TalkBack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309150/what-is-the-difference-between-android-focusable-and-importantforaccessibility-w)